# POCO Model and Calculated fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have POCO entities based on the database model (example: Company entity is based on Companies table). In order to display a couple of calculated fields in the view, I added corresponding properties in the ViewModel.

Should I have these calculated fields in the Model(POCO entity) itself

or

Should I have another class that maps Models to ViewModels and vice versa and set these properties in my ViewModel there?

Comment: If the calculated fields are for use in a view, then a view model is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewModel is the way to go.

But in case of "emergencies", you can have additional properties in your POCO
with the attribute [NotMapped]